# Play and record sound using pyaudio simultaneously

Tags: python, numpy, audio, talkback

I'm trying to create a program to talk back at once. I can't seem to get it to work. Some websites say use `numpy` arrays but I don't know how.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd

fs = 44100
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE, input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
myarray = []
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    myarray.append(data)

    myrecording = sd.play(myarray, fs, channels=2)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "SoundTest.py", line 24, in  myrecording = sd.play(myarray, fs, channels=2) line 2170, in check_data dtype = _check_dtype(data.dtype) File "/home/lordvile/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 2316, in _check_dtype raise TypeError('Unsupported data type: ' + repr(dtype)) TypeError: Unsupported data type: 'string32768'

Comment: What isn't workng? Explain.

Comment: @Michael I really have no idea. This is the error. I removed a few lines since it wont fit...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SoundTest.py", line 24, in <module>
    myrecording = sd.play(myarray, fs, channels=2)
line 2170, in check_data
    dtype = _check_dtype(data.dtype)
  File "/home/lordvile/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 2316, in _check_dtype
    raise TypeError('Unsupported data type: ' + repr(dtype))
TypeError: Unsupported data type: 'string32768'

Comment: @SubhadityaMukherjee Update your question with your Tracebak please.

Comment: Looks like `sounddevice` does not like `pyaudio`s data. Have you checked that the format is compatible?

Comment: myarray is not a numpy array, but a list!

Comment: @handle It appears so.. No I havent checked actually. To be honest im still in school and I dont think we will be doing numpy at all.. I dont understand how do I create the list with the audio data? It doesnt seem to be working. And thanks for helping..

Comment: You shouldn't mix `PyAudio` and the `sounddevice` module. Use either one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

Below are examples for both 'PyAudio' and 'Sounddevice' for simultaneous recording and playback. The most important thing for me was to explicitly set the input and output devices to a valid value. Hence, I included printing for sound devices for both examples.

Sounddevice:

Works like a charm compared to PyAudio. At least for me, sounddevice offers a stable interface for simultaneous audio recording and playback. Though there are a few console outputs complaining about a input/output over-/underflow, the record/playback regenerates and eventually I get a fluently working 'echo'.

```
import sounddevice as sd

fs = 44100

def callback(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    if status:
        print(status)
    outdata[:] = indata

print(sd.query_devices())

try:
    with sd.Stream(device=(0,1), samplerate=fs, dtype='float32', latency=None, channels=2, callback=callback):
        input()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

PyAudio:

This code should(?) work. For me it does not work consistently. It already worked for about a minute once but usually I get the Error: "OSError: [Errno -9981] Input overflowed". I don't know why it always throws this error, but feel free to try it out yourself.

```
import pyaudio
import json

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
CHUNK = 1024
RATE = 44100

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

for i in range(audio.get_device_count()):
    print(json.dumps(audio.get_device_info_by_index(i), indent=2))

stream = audio.open(format              = FORMAT,
                    channels            = CHANNELS,
                    rate                = RATE,
                    input               = True,
                    output              = True,
                    input_device_index  = 0,
                    output_device_index = 1,
                    frames_per_buffer   = CHUNK)

try:
    frames = []
    print("* echoing")
    print("Press CTRL+C to stop")
    while True:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
        if len(frames)>0:
            stream.write(frames.pop(0),CHUNK)
    print("* done echoing")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()
```

Comment: For me who uses PyAudio, explicitly specifying the input device index and output device index solves the problem

Comment: The two examples compare `sounddevice` using "callback" mode with `pyaudio` using "blocking" mode. Both modules can use both modes, so it would be more meaningful to compare them using the same mode.

Comment: Note that `pyaudio` has the `exception_on_overflow` parameter for `read()` (see https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.Stream.read), which is `True` by default. If you set this to `False`, you can avoid raising the mentioned exception (but I don't recommend ignoring those over- and underflows!).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have requirement to use `pyaudio`, but here is an example using `sounddevice`.

Below example records audio from microphone for `#seconds` as per variable `duration` which you can modify as per your requirements.

Same contents are played back using standard audio output (speakers).

More on this [here](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.4/)

**Working Code**

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

fs=44100
duration = 10  # seconds
myrecording = sd.rec(duration * fs, samplerate=fs, channels=2, dtype='float64')
print "Recording Audio for %s seconds" %(duration)
sd.wait()
print "Audio recording complete , Playing recorded Audio"
sd.play(myrecording, fs)
sd.wait()
print "Play Audio Complete"
```

**Output**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Recording Audio for 10 seconds
Audio recording complete , Playing recorded Audio
Play Audio Complete
>>>
```