# Making a real time chat platform-sounddevice problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, chat, real-time, python-sounddevice

I'm gonna make a chatting platform in which two people can have voice chat in real-time. (Like skype). The question is that how can I have the sounddevice module always listening and recording? Look at the code below which I've got from an answer to this question: [Play and record sound using pyaudio simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878908/play-and-record-sound-using-pyaudio-simultaneously)

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

fs=44100


duration = 10  # seconds 
# (I don't want it for 10 seconds, I want it to record as long as the user doesn't close the session)


myrecording = sd.rec(duration * fs, samplerate=fs, channels=2, dtype='float64')
print "Recording Audio for %s seconds" %(duration)
sd.wait()
print "Audio recording complete"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sd.rec()` only if the desired duration is known beforehand.

If you want to record for a yet unknown time, you'll have to use the `Stream` (or `InputStream`) API.

For an example, see [rec_unlimited.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/rec_unlimited.py).